# Get directory from which script was called from

Tags: bash, scripting, directory, printing

I have a script `doSmth` in `/usr/bin`. Is it possible to get and print the directory *the script was called from*?

So if I call `doSmth` from `/home/me` the output will be `/home/me`.

Comment: In what language?

Comment: Uhh, in bash :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you invoke a command in the shell, the new process inherits the working directory of the parent. Here are two ways get the working directory:

```
echo "$PWD" # variable
pwd         # builtin command
```

Answer (score 1):

By "directory it was called from" you seem to mean its working directory. You can change this inside the script using e.g., `cd`, but before you do so, `pwd` will print it out. It'll also likely be in the variable `$PWD`

If you'll need the initial working directory after changing it, just save it at the top of your script (before changing it)

```shell
#!/bin/bash
initial_wd=`pwd`

# ... do a lot of stuff ...
# ⋮

cd "$initial_wd"
```

If you're using this to get back to the directory you started in, see also `pushd` and `popd`.

Comment: In bash, there is also "$OLDPWD".

Comment: @jordanm Indeed there is, but that won't necessarily be the initial working directory (e.g., if you've used `cd` twice)

Comment: $OLDPWD is what I need; I run bash scripts from the CMD Prompt on Win7 and this was the environment variable that held the directory I run the script from. Cheers