# How to find the directory from where the script is invoked without using $pwd in the my script

Tags: linux

suppose there is a script "/home/abc/test.go". Someone else went to another directory lets assume "/etc/random/" and executed the script "test.go".

Now I want to know from where the script was invoked.

Can anyone help me with the command to know from where the script was invoked(/etc/random/)??

I tried "lsof" but it gives the files that the script is working on and the location of the script(/home/abc/) but not from where it is invoked.

Note:- I don't want to use $pwd in the script. I am looking for a command that can just display the directory from where the mentioned script was executed(invoked).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the current working directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188182/how-can-i-get-the-current-working-directory) Or more exactly: [Get directory from which script was called from](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52916/get-directory-from-which-script-was-called-from)

Comment: No, i have checked those and my question is completely different.

I want to know from which directory the script was executed.

Comment: You could use the phrase "find the current working directory of the shell that invoked the script" to avoid any misinterpretation of your question.

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski

yes exactly... I need a command to use outside of the script.

Comment: Please make it clear in the question itself. When you say "without using `$pwd` in my script" the first thought is you want to use something else *in the script*.

Answer (score 1):

The current directory is stored in the variable `$PWD`.

You could store that value somewhere at the beginning of the script to e.g. output it or save it in a log.

Comment: The script is executed by another user and We can't modify the script 

As an admin, I Just want to know the directory from where he executed the script 

I mean is there a general command to find that...??

Comment: No, there isn't, unless you set up a complete audit system. You could also have a look at the user's shell history.